# problem with Issue dates

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime

i have this in my C# program:

```
if (DateTime.Now >= myDateTime1 && DateTime.Now <= myDateTime2)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
```

this are the values:

```
DateTime.Now = 20/06/11 10:55:43

myDateTime1  = 20/06/11 11:29:09

myDateTime2  = 21/06/11 11:31:07
```

but why this sentence return me `False`  ?

**EDIT:** I need to compare only Dates, not with time.

Comment: Hey guys why is `2 > 1` returning `true`???

Comment: 10:55:43 is not larger then 11:29:09. While I was writing this comment, 4 new answers appeared with the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the dates you've given, `DateTime.Now` is before `myDateTime1`, so `DateTime.Now >= myDateTime1` is evaluating to `false`, which means the whole if statement is evaluating to `false`, so it's running the `else` code, which returns `false`.

FYI if you set a breakpoint on the if statement (press F9), when the program stops you can hover the mouse over the binary operators (such as `<=`, `&&` and `>=`) to show what they evaluate to.

EDIT: If you only want to compare the date, then use `if (DateTime.Today >= myDateTime1.Date && DateTime.Today <= myDateTime2.Date)`

Comment: thanks for the help !! - i need only the date i dont need the time - how to do it ?

Comment: Instead of using `DateTime.Today` you should use `DateTime.Now.Date`

Answer (score 1):

Because `DateTime.Now` is Less than `myDateTime1`. First condition gets false and next condition won't run. If have any query still, you can ask or correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, DateTime.Now is not between myDateTime1 and myDateTime2, which is what the if statement is requiring, so it returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Because

```
(20/06/11 10:55:43) >= (20/06/11 11:29:09)
```

is false :)